# Is it possable to set opacity for only <p> but not <a> element?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I would like to add opacity all text in this

element but not for  without adding (span) any HTML tag

```
<p>Handcrafted by:<a href="https://trendytheme.net">TrendyTheme</a></p>
```

I used like that:

```
p:not(a){
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `rgba()`

Working example

https://jsfiddle.net/shuts13/cLugphbq/2/

```
p {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
a {
  color: blue;
}
```

also you can use it for background

```
p {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background: rgba(33,33,33,0.5);
}
a {
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: if it helps you, please correct like right answer or, upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your text to a `<span>` inside the `<p>` and create a class that add opacity to that element

```css
p span {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Handcrafted by:</span><a href="https://trendytheme.net" rel="nofollow noreferrer">TrendyTheme</a></p>
```

hope that help.

Comment: The author mentioned => No Span!!